# How to fix TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression?

Tags: python, async-await, aiohttp

Running the following code:

```
async def generate_url(self, ding_id):
    data = await self.s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
        'Bucket': '...',
        'Key': '{}.mp4'.format(ding_id)
        }
    )

    return data

def convert_to_json(self, data):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for ding in dings:
        tasks.append(self.generate_url(ding))

    video_ids = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    loop.close()
```

causes error:

```
'Key': '{}.mp4'.format(ding_id) 
TypeError: object str can't be used in 'await' expression`
```

I use an async request library `aiohttp`. How to fix that problem?

Comment: There’s no request being made; it just generates a string.

Comment: I didn't understand. I think I call `generate_presigned_url` and made a request. However, how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `generate_presigned_url` method is synchronous and [simply returns the URL](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url), you don't need to use await here.